# Ограничение возможностей Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

Здравствуйте.
Хочу в своей программе использовать Jinja2, но при этом такие возможности как включение блоков и наследование шаблонов мне не нужны. Можно ли в Jinja API сделать, чтобы синтаксис {% block ... %}, {% extends ... %}, {% include ... %} игнорировался?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что официального способа нет, но можно пойти на хак, который заключается в том, что в модуле jinja2.parser есть объявление переменной _statement_keywords, которая содержит множество типов блоков. В исходниках эта переменная равна

```
_statement_keywords = frozenset(['for', 'if', 'block', 'extends', 'print',
                                 'macro', 'include', 'from', 'import',
                                 'set'])
```

Если изменить значение этой переменной на

```
_statement_keywords = frozenset(['for', 'if', 'set'])
```

то это то, что мне нужно.